# Command not found when executing in remote server using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, users, ssh-tunneling

I am trying to automate a few steps that I need to execute in a remote linux machine from my local ubuntu computer.

My shell script is as follows :-

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh XYZ '

qlogin -l cuda=1

'
```

When I am trying to execute it by collecting the `./fileName.sh` . I am getting

```
bash: line 2: qlogin: command not found
```

However, when I do it manually i.e. ssh into the cluster and than run this command , I am able to execute it.

**Troubleshooting till now**

1. Both the local and remote terminal is bash . This I got by `echo $0`
2. When I manually ssh into the remote and print the path for qlogin (via `which qlogin`). I get

```
/opt/ge/bin/lx-amd64/qlogin
```

However, when I do the same via the script,I don't get any which means that qlogin is not installed.

3. Finally, I  the user executing the script and the user that logs in when i manually ssh are not the same (got it by printing the `who`).

What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want in this case is:

```bsh
ssh XYZ "qlogin -l cuda=1"
```

or

```bsh
ssh XYZ "export TERM=xterm ; qlogin -l cuda=1"
```

In case you get some error about the `TERM` variable not being set, or:

```bsh
ssh XYZ << 'EOF'
qlogin -l cuda=1
EOF
```

If you have multiple command to run.

Lastly, since I'm sure that this could work if the above don't:

```bsh
ssh XYZ << 'EOF'
shopt -s expand_aliases
source .bashrc
qlogin -l cuda=1
EOF
```

As you probably noticed, the last one may work if the other one don't, mainly if `qlogin` isn't in one of the default exported PATH, and is either:

- aliased *somewhere* else (eg: some remote servers like to keep their install script in a mounted NFS folder that isn't exported in PATH)
- if it's part of a larger function/script made of functions.

You could look at the output of `env`, `alias` and `whereis` to make sure of that. Replacing `.bashrc` with anything else that may mention the full path of the `qlogin` command, such as `.profile` or other ones come to mind.

Comment: It didnot work.

Comment: what was the error? see the edit i made in case this work for you.

Comment: maybe try to use the full path for the command instead: `/opt/ge/bin/lx-amd64/qlogin` in the example above @Echo

Comment: Hi, I did something similar . ```ssh XYZ '

source /opt/ge/default/common/settings.sh && qlogin -l cuda=1

'``` This helped. The issue was with login session as doing it via ssh script leads to a non login session and that caused the issue.

Comment: yeah, that's why i mentioned the last one, because i thought it might be an alias or script that was sourced somewhere :) glad it's fixed @Echo